# count users in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of usernames, and fans which looks like this:

```
Username, Fan
Bob, Rita
Bob, Sue
Bob, Rita
Sue, Bob
Rita, Sue
Rita, Bob
Rita, Sue
```

I want to be able to perform a count so the resulting table looks like this:

```
Rita, Bob, 2
Sue, Bob, 1
Sue, Rita, 2
Bob, Sue, 1
Bob, Rita, 1
```

Basically meaning, Bob has fanned Rita twice, Bob has fanned Sue twice, Bob fanned Sue once etc etc.

Any ideas what the mysql statement should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Username, Fan, count(*) as count
FROM table_name 
GROUP By Username, Fan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Username, Fan, count(Fan) 
from your_table
group by Username
order by Username
```

Comment: your group by should be `GROUP BY Username, Fan`

Comment: There is too much grouping here, you need to split it up.

Answer (score 0):

A subselect could be what you want

```
SELECT a.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab AS b WHERE b.feld = a.feld) AS cnt
FROM tab AS a
WHERE ...
```

Comment: This would have waaaay too much overhead if it is a big table